# TabView add TabItem and pass data

Tags: c#, winui-3

i'm fairly new with C# and WinUI.
I have an app with a TabView with one constant tab that contains a DataGrid, when i double click any row in the datagrid it creates a new TabItem.

What i'm trying to do is populate the newly opened TabItem with data, depending on which row was double clicked. The data in the newly opened TabItems can't be reloaded when you switch tabs because the are supposed to be editable.

How would i go about populating the newly opened tabs?
I have found solutions that dynamically populate the tab data when you switch tabs, but if you have edited anything in them previously it would be overwritten.

What i have so far, not much.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Tasks.xaml (containing the TabView and Datagrid)

```
<TabView x:Name="Tabs" AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddButtonClick" 
         TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested" Loaded="TabView_Loaded" 
         TabDroppedOutside="TabView_TabDroppedOutside" CanDragTabs="True">
    <TabViewItem Header="Tasks" IsClosable="False">
        <TabViewItem.IconSource>
            <SymbolIconSource Symbol="Home" />
        </TabViewItem.IconSource>
        <Grid>
            <Grid>
                <DataGrid:SfDataGrid x:Name="DataGrid"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                        ShowSortNumbers="True" AllowResizingColumns="True" AllowDraggingColumns="True" 
                        SelectionUnit="Row" CellDoubleTapped="DataGrid_CellDoubleTapped" 
                        AllowGrouping="True" ShowGroupDropArea="True" 
                        AllowFiltering="True" FilterRowPosition="FixedTop">
                    <DataGrid:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGrid:GridNumericColumn MappingName="ColumnId" HeaderText="ID" ColumnWidthMode="Auto" IsHidden="True"/>
                        <DataGrid:GridNumericColumn MappingName="ColumnStatus" HeaderText="STATUS" ColumnWidthMode="Auto" ImmediateUpdateColumnFilter="True"/>
                        <DataGrid:GridTextColumn MappingName="ColumnTaskNr" HeaderText="NR" ColumnWidthMode="Auto" ImmediateUpdateColumnFilter="True"/>
                        <DataGrid:GridTextColumn MappingName="ColumnCustomerName" HeaderText="KUND" ColumnWidthMode="Auto" ImmediateUpdateColumnFilter="True"/>
                        <DataGrid:GridTextColumn MappingName="ColumnCustomT2" HeaderText="GÄLLER" ColumnWidthMode="Auto" ImmediateUpdateColumnFilter="True"/>
                        <DataGrid:GridTextColumn MappingName="ColumnTask" HeaderText="UPPDRAG" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" ImmediateUpdateColumnFilter="True"/>
                        <DataGrid:GridDateColumn MappingName="ColumnCreatedDate" HeaderText="SKAPAT TIDPUNKT" ColumnWidthMode="Auto" ImmediateUpdateColumnFilter="True" FilterRowEditorType="Date"/>
                        <DataGrid:GridNumericColumn MappingName="ColumnPriority" HeaderText="PRIORITET" ColumnWidthMode="Auto" ImmediateUpdateColumnFilter="True"/>
                        <DataGrid:GridTextColumn MappingName="ColumnCustomT1" HeaderText="ATT GÖRA" ColumnWidthMode="Auto" ImmediateUpdateColumnFilter="True"/>
                        <DataGrid:GridTextColumn MappingName="ColumnCustomerRef" HeaderText="KONTAKTPERSON" ColumnWidthMode="Auto" ImmediateUpdateColumnFilter="True"/>
                    </DataGrid:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid:SfDataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
enter code here
```

Tasks.xaml.cs (function containing the function that creates a new tab)

```
private void DataGrid_CellDoubleTapped(object sender, Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.DataGrid.GridCellDoubleTappedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataGrid.SelectedIndex = this.DataGrid.ResolveToRecordIndex(e.RowColumnIndex.RowIndex);


    int rowIndex = e.RowColumnIndex.RowIndex;
    int columnIndex = this.DataGrid.ResolveToGridVisibleColumnIndex(e.RowColumnIndex.ColumnIndex);
    var recordIndex = this.DataGrid.ResolveToRecordIndex(rowIndex);
    var record1 = this.DataGrid.View.Records.GetItemAt(recordIndex);
    var mappingName = this.DataGrid.Columns[columnIndex].MappingName;

    string TaskNr = record1.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("ColumnTaskNr").GetValue(record1).ToString();

    TabViewItem newItem = new TabViewItem();

    newItem.Header = $"{TaskNr}";
    newItem.IconSource = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.SymbolIconSource() { Symbol = Symbol.Document };

    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.Navigate(typeof(TaskDetails));

    newItem.Content = frame;

    Tabs.TabItems.Add(newItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass ViewModels to each `TabItem`s:

For example:

```cs
public partial class  ItemViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _text = string.Empty;
}
```

[ObservarbableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty)

```cs
public sealed partial class TabViewContentPage : Page
{
    public TabViewContentPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ItemViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App14.TabViewContentPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:App14"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

```cs
private void TabView_AddButtonClick(TabView sender, object args)
{
    ItemViewModel itemViewModel = new()
    {
        Text = $"{TabViewControl.TabItems.Count}",
    };

    TabViewContentPage tabViewContentPage = new()
    {
        ViewModel = itemViewModel,
    };

    Frame frame = new()
    {
        Content = tabViewContentPage,
    };


    TabViewItem newTabViewItem = new()
    {
        Header = "New Tab",
        Content = frame,
    };

    this.TabViewControl.TabItems.Add(newTabViewItem);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm trying this solution but i get 
The type or namespace name 'ObservableObject' could not be found.
Where is it located?
I'm using .net 6
I have also added System.Collections.ObjectModel

Comment: I managed to get it working, but i'm not sure what i did.
Thanks you very much this solution worked perfectly.